# Why is /bin/true 27168 bytes in size?

Tags: linux, size

`ls -l /bin/true` shows it being 27168 bytes in size, whereas a c program that just returns 0 is [much smaller](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html). Also, running `objdump -d /bin/true` gives a huge assembly program with many system calls. Why is all this needed for a program that just "does nothing successfully"?

Comment: `true` is actually one of the smallest programs of the `coreutils` package. It has 78 lines of in the source code of which 58 are code, the rest are comments and blank lines. http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/true.c;hb=HEAD is the source file for true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because apart from returning 0 it also handles *help* and *version* options, plus it contains some comments inside.

You can figure it by yourself by cloning the sources from [Github](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils), and looking at the content of *coreutils/src/true.c*.